# Raconter ta ive

Tags: sens, verlan

I have heard the following sentence in the TV series Marseille:

- Toi, ferme ta gueule! Compris? Me racontes pas ta ive.

What does "ive" mean here? The only meaning I have found is a plant, but that does not make sense here. Is it a verlan of "vie"? Shouldn't that be "eiv"?

Comment: Are you sure it is not ta vie ?

Comment: I'm sure. You can check it on S02E06 06:57 (29:56 before end).

Comment: Why is this question off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*ive* is the “verlan” of *vie*.

“Verlan” is inverting phonems, not letters.

Comment: Toto, pourquoi alors pas ton ive au lieu de ta ive ?

Comment: @Dimitris: Tout simplement,je pense, pare que les personnes qui l'utilisent ne maîtrisent pas forcement la grammaire !  Ils doivent penser que puisqu'on dit **ta** vie, on doit dire **ta** ive alors qu'effectivement il faudrait die **ton** ive.

Comment: It's gangster talk, so that surely explains the grammatically incorrect feminine possessive pronoun in the sentence. @Toto if verlan only inverts phonems and does not care abot letters, could the verlan "ive" be spelled "iv" as well ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: I guess *iv* is also correct because there're no real rules for *verlan*.